# Distance between the boundary of a set and the interior of the set

Tags: real-analysis

I was given to prove that **given $(E, d)$ a metric space, $A \subset E$ non empty and $x \in E$ then $d(x, A) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow x \in \bar{A}$ where $\bar{A}$ is the closure of $A$.**

Which I attacked as follows:

- Let $A$ be open then the boundary $\partial{A} \not\subset A$ and let $x \in \partial{A}$ We know by definition that $d(x, a) > 0, \forall a\not=x$ and $d(x, a)=0$ if $a=x$.
  Since $d(x, A)=inf \{d(x, a): a\in A\}$ then $0=d(x, A)$ implies $x \in A$ which by hypothesis we know is not true, creating a contrdiction and therefore the proposition would be false.
- At the same time we know that there exists an open ball $B(x, r), r > 0$ such that $B$ has elements of A (non empty intersection). Let $a \in B \wedge a \in A$ then we know $0 \leq d(x, A) \leq d(x, a) < r$ when $r \rightarrow0, d(x, A) \rightarrow 0$. Can we conclude $d(x, A)=0$? How do we save the contradiction at the beginning? Or this is not true for all "d"s?

**NOTE**: For the rest of the problem it is easy to show that if $x$ is in the interior of $A$ then the distance is zero and if it is in the interior of the complement of $A$ then the distance is not zero

Comment: What do you mean by $\partial A\notin A$? $\partial A$ is not a point. "Since $d(x,A)=\inf\{d(x,A)\,:\, a\in A\}$ then $0=d(x,A)$ implies $x\in A$": care to prove that?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I've meant $\partial{A} \not\subset A$. Thanks! Your question made me realize that I've mistaken the infimum with the minimum. If it were the minimum, x would have to be inside of that set, but since is the infimum my statement does not hold.

Comment: More so for every open ball $B(x,r)$ where $(r >0)$ there exists $a_r \in A \cap B(x,r)$ and there is a sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$ such that $d(a_n,x) \to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Sassatelli's question in the comments section I realized that I've mistaken the infimum with the minimum. So there's no contradiction, since it is not true that $d(x, A)=inf \{d(x, a): a\in A\}$ then $0=d(x, A)$ implies $x \in A$.